# How can I preserve the element names of a list when using sapply in R?

Tags: r

I have a function called diseaseMutation that needs to be ran on data frame joint2 multiple times, each with different conditions. For instance, three copies of the code would look like the following:

```
Colon <- diseaseMutation(joint2, "Colon/Colorectal Cancer")
Bladder <- diseaseMutation(joint2, "Bladder Cancer")
Lung <- diseaseMutation(joint2, "Lung Cancer")
```

I want to use the following lapply function to run the loop diseaseMutation on the diseases, and save the disease name as the name of each element.

```
results <- lapply(unique(joint2$disease),
                  function(j) diseaseMutation(joint2, j))
```

How can I apply names post run in order to save the diseases as the output names?

Comment: `names(results) <- unique(joint2$disease)`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Simpler approach, no need extra packages

```r
results <- lapply(setNames(nm = unique(joint2$disease)),
                  function(j) diseaseMutation(joint2, j))
```